# Setting text in JLabel in a loop

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlabel

```
                start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                FileReader filereader1 = new FileReader("virus_database/point.dat");
                JTextField jtextfield1 = new JTextField();
                jtextfield1.read(filereader1, null);
                point = Integer.parseInt(jtextfield1.getText());
                filereader1.close();
                scanFileName.setText("");
                scanFileName.setText("Please wait. Loading Database...");
                for(int i = 0; i < point && cmd != 1; i++)
                {
                    FileReader filereader4 = new FileReader((new StringBuilder()).append("virus_database/malware").append(i).append(".res").toString());
                    JTextField jtextfield4 = new JTextField();
                    jtextfield4.read(filereader4, null);
                    database[i] = jtextfield4.getText();
                    filereader4.close();
                    int k6 = (i * 100) / point;
                }
                scanFileName.setText(".");
```

I still don't understand why the output in scanFileName (Jlabel) is directly showing "." instead of "", "Please Wait. Loading Database...", and then ".". Please help. I'd be grateful to you.

Comment: I think you need to show more code.  Please [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by having a read through [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/).

Swing is a single threaded framework, this means that anything which blocks this thread (like `Thread.sleep`) will prevent the framework from processing new events (including paint requests).

While there are any number of ways you might make this work, probably the easiest is a Swing `javax.swing.Timer`.  Take a look at [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details...

Comment: Thank you :)
The problem now is entirely different.

Comment: See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)

Comment: Thank you so much. SwingWorker is what I exactly needed.